# Jquery How to skip to next iteration

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table and need to append a `<span>` to both td:first-child cell and td:first-child cell.

**Problems:**

1. There is already exist a `<span>` in the first td.  How to skip appending if a `<span>` is already there?  (If if statement somehow doesn't work)
2. I wonder why my code doesn't append `<span>` in a td:last-child
3. Please take a look at the second and third rows of the first column, the insert text comes after text in the cell (Jill 2 first-col, Jill 2 first-col).  How to move insert text in front?

Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr td:first-child').append('<span class="first-col"> first-col</span>');
  if ($('tr td:first-child span').length) {
    return false
  }
  $('tr td:last-child').append('<span class="second-col"> second-col</span>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="first-col"> first-col</span>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill 2</td>
    <td>Smith 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill 3</td>
    <td>Smith 3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: **both td:first-child cell and td:first-child cell** What does that mean? Should the second `first-child` be `last-child`?

Comment: Hi Barmar, If I use `nth-child(2)` for `last-child`, it works.

Comment: `if ($('tr td:first-child span').length)` is always true... what did you expect

Comment: `if ($('tr td:first-child span').length)`, I expect not to append `<span>` in that cell anymore because it already has `<span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use method `each()` to define the current `tr td:first-child` as `this`, using the `find()` method with the `span` tag specified in it.

```
$("tr td:first-child").each(function () {
    if (!$(this).find("span").length) {
        $(this).append('<span class="first-col"> first-col</span>');
    }
});
```

Inserting a `span` tag with class `first-col`, place it inside a condition, with a boolean operator `NOT`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr td:first-child").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).find("span").length) {
            $(this).append('<span class="first-col"> first-col</span>');
        }
    });
    $("tr td:last-child").append('<span class="second-col"> second-col</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="first-col"> first-col</span>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill 2</td>
        <td>Smith 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill 3</td>
        <td>Smith 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi s.kuznetsov, Thank you very much for sharing!  That works as expect.  I am wondering instead of using `if (!$(this).find("span").length)` as your code, I try to use `if (!$(this).is('span')) `, or `if (!$(this).has('span'))`, these don't work out.  Any idea?

Comment: @abcidd, Hi. Method `.has` works great for me. You forgot to specify the `length` property. - `!$(this).has("span").length)`. See link - https://api.jquery.com/has/. Logically, it makes no difference which method you use in a given task.

Comment: @abcidd, I forgot to write about `is()`. This method checks the **current element**, but not the child. In order to define the `<span>` tag, you need to add `.children()`. This is how it should work - `!$(this).children().is("span")`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `if` statement around the code that adds the new span. Since you put it *after*, the condition is always true, so you return and never get to the code that adds the span to the last child.

You also need to use `.each()` so you're testing just one TD at a time, not all of them.

Instead you can use `:not(:has(span))` to exclude TDs that already have a span from the selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr td:first-child:not(:has(span))').append('<span class="first-col"> first-col</span>');
  $('tr td:last-child').append('<span class="second-col"> second-col</span>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="first-col"> first-col</span>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill 2</td>
    <td>Smith 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill 3</td>
    <td>Smith 3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmar for your help!  It works as expect.